# Enabling button when checkbox in datagridview is clicked?

Tags: c#, datagridview

As the title suggests, my code is designed to detect if there's at least one checkbox checked on datagridview. If there is, a button will be enabled. If not, enabled property becomes false.

```
public void validatecheck(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        var senderGrid = (DataGridView)sender;

        if (senderGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn && e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dtgeducation.Rows)
            {
                if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value) == true)
                {
                    btnaddclass.Enabled = true;

                    break;
                }

                else
                {
                    btnaddclass.Enabled = false;
                }

            }
        }
```

This code still not working. Maybe I'm overlooking a essential part. Any help is greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the "why this code isn't working?" questions are off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code with the debugger?

Comment: What do you mean by `Not working`? Are you getting error? What unexpected behavior you are seeing? Did you try to debug the code ?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya By not working, I mean that the button doesn't become enabled when one checkbox in the datagridview is checked. There's no error warnings or anything. 
I tried to debug the code previously by using DataGridViewCheckboxCell but it barely worked. By barely, it refers that the checkbox worked ONLY for a limited number of times. If the checkbox is clicked many times, the button becomes permanently disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would bind a bool property in your view-model to the IsChecked property on the checkbox, then assign that property's value to update the Enabled property of the button.